# How to Create a Folder After Copying Files Based on Values in Cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

So I want after copying then make a folder according to the folder name in the "code" column, so the example below will be 2 folders, namely the WSO.24 folder containing 3 image files and the WSO.23 folder containing 2 image files.
I just want a slight modification in my code

| PATH | FILENAME | CODE | ITEM | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \\SERVER-PC\Catalog\CATALOG BORDIR FINAL\BORDIR\WSO-24\WSO.24(A).jpg | WSO.24(A).jpg | WSO.24 | WOLLPEACH SO-2018 WSO.24 | V |
| \\SERVER-PC\Catalog\CATALOG BORDIR FINAL\BORDIR\WSO-24\WSO.24(B).jpg | WSO.24(B).jpg | WSO.24 | WOLLPEACH SO-2018 WSO.24 | V |
| \\SERVER-PC\Catalog\CATALOG BORDIR FINAL\BORDIR\WSO-24\WSO.24(C).jpg | WSO.24(C).jpg | WSO.24 | WOLLPEACH SO-2018 WSO.24 | V |
| \\SERVER-PC\Catalog\CATALOG BORDIR FINAL\BORDIR\WSO-23\WSO.23(A).jpg | WSO.23(A).jpg | WSO.23 | WOLLPEACH SO-2018 WSO.23 | V |
| \\SERVER-PC\Catalog\CATALOG BORDIR FINAL\BORDIR\WSO-23\WSO.23(B).jpg | WSO.23(B).jpg | WSO.23 | WOLLPEACH SO-2018 WSO.23 | V |

```
Sub copyFiles()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrA, i As Long, k As Long
  Dim fileD As FileDialog, strDestFold As String, FSO As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' last row on A:A column
  arrA = sh.Range("A2:E" & lastR).Value2                   'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select the destination folder!"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strDestFold = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"   'select the destination folder
        End If
  End With
  If strDestFold = "" Then Exit Sub                         'in case of  not selecting any folder
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
     If UCase(arrA(i, 5)) = "V" Then                         'copy the file only if a "V" exists in column E:E
        If FSO.FileExists(arrA(i, 1)) Then                    'check if the path in excel is correct
            FSO.COPYFILE arrA(i, 1), strDestFold, True     'copy the file (True, to overwrite the file if it exists)
            k = k + 1
        Else
            MsgBox arrA(i, 1) & " file could not be found." & vbCrLf & _
                        "Please, check the spelling and correct the file full path!", vbInformation, _
                        "File does not exist..."
        End If
     End If
  Next i
  MsgBox "Copied " & k & " files in " & strDestFold, , "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: @braX , Thank you for your response, I have not been able to get a solution from the post link you provided

Comment: If your path is going to be a UNC path, then it should start with 2 backslashes, not one. Also make sure you are not using any illegal characters. Maybe it would help if we could see what exactly you tried using from that link?

Comment: Also, your "path" is including the name of the file too, which not only is redundant, but also will cause a problem if you do not remove it before using it to create a folder.

Comment: @braX , sorry I got the backslashes wrong because in the table in the post I made 2 backslashes tp the output became 1 and now I make 3 backslashes then the output becomes 2

Comment: Are you planning on showing us what you tried with your attempt?

Comment: @braX , thanks for the response, my plan is to create the appropriate folder in the "CODE" column after the copy process. so the code I posted can only copy the file

Comment: So you are not going to show us the code you attempted to use from that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your code is correct, I will not implement that part, just write the part about creating the folder and copyng the file into it:

ONLY THESE FOUR LINES. DONE:

```
Dim subFolderName As String, fileName As String
```

```
 subFolderName = arrA(i, 3): fileName = arrA(i, 2)
 If Not FSO.FolderExists(strDestFold + subFolderName) Then FSO.CreateFolder (strDestFold + subFolderName)
 FSO.COPYFILE arrA(i, 1), strDestFold + subFolderName + "\" + fileName, True    'copy the file (True, to overwrite the file if it exists)
```

```vb
Sub copyFiles()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrA, i As Long, k As Long
  Dim fileD As FileDialog, strDestFold As String, FSO As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' last row on A:A column
  arrA = sh.Range("A2:E" & lastR).Value2                   'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select the destination folder!"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strDestFold = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"   'select the destination folder
        End If
  End With
  If strDestFold = "" Then Exit Sub                         'in case of  not selecting any folder

  Dim subFolderName As String, fileName As String

  For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
     If UCase(arrA(i, 5)) = "V" Then                         'copy the file only if a "V" exists in column E:E
        If FSO.FileExists(arrA(i, 1)) Then                    'check if the path in excel is correct

            subFolderName = arrA(i, 3): fileName = arrA(i, 2)
            If Not FSO.FolderExists(strDestFold + subFolderName) Then FSO.CreateFolder (strDestFold + subFolderName)
            FSO.COPYFILE arrA(i, 1), strDestFold + subFolderName + "\" + fileName, True    'copy the file (True, to overwrite the file if it exists)

            k = k + 1
        Else
            MsgBox arrA(i, 1) & " file could not be found." & vbCrLf & _
                        "Please, check the spelling and correct the file full path!", vbInformation, _
                        "File does not exist..."
        End If
     End If
  Next i
  
  Rem Release Memory
  Set FSO = Nothing: Set fileD = Nothing: Set sh = Nothing
  
  MsgBox "Copied " & k & " files in " & strDestFold, , "Ready..."
End Sub
```